# What does __PACKAGE__->{foo} mean?

Tags: perl

I'm refactoring a perl module in legacy code, and this is a function from the module:

```
sub get_user {
    my $user = __PACKAGE__->{user};
    if (!defined $user) {
       # more code
       __PACKAGE__->{user} = $user;
    }
    return $user;
}
```

This module compiles under `use strict`. And there's no package variables defined.
What does `__PACKAGE__->{user}` mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__PACKAGE__` is the name of the current package; your code is using it as a symbolic hash reference.  So if your package is foo, it is setting `$foo::foo{'user'}`.  This is kind of a strange thing to do; I suspect it may be an error.

Because it's a symbolic reference, it shouldn't be allowed under strict.  It seems to be, however, at least when the current package has multiple parts (e.g. Foo::Bar, not just Foo).
I wouldn't depend on this bug staying in effect, though.

Comment: My guess is that `__PACKAGE__` in *eugene y*'s example is a `Compound::Namespace::Construction` rather than `SimpleOne` (no colons), which seems to circumvent stricture for me under 5.10.

Comment: ... of course!  Because `__PACKAGE__->{key}` in a simple namespace is, e.g., `main->{key}` (error: `Global symbol "%main" requires explicit package name`), but in a compound namespace is, e.g., `My::Pkg->{key}`, which is a fully qualified reference to the hash `%Pkg` under package `My`.  I would expect a "bareword" error, but the special processing of `__PACKAGE__ must sidestep that.

Comment: ah.  that seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Somebody please report this bug. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

{
    package X::Y;

    our $user = 10;
    say $user;

    say __PACKAGE__;

}


--output:--
10
X::Y
```

The package name may be 'X::Y' but the symbol table for the package is named 'X::Y::' (note the trailing colons).  A symbol table is a perl hash, and the keys in the %X::Y:: hash are the global names used in the X::Y package.  The corresponding values are the typeglobs for each name:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

{
    package X::Y;

    our $user = 10;
    say $user;

    say __PACKAGE__;
    say $X::Y::{user};   #Hash name is %X::Y::


}

--output:--
10
X::Y
*X::Y::user
```

But the expression in the op:

```
__PACKAGE__->{user}
```

is equivalent to:

```
'X::Y'->{user}
```

I fail to see how that line will succeed in retrieving anything from a hash whose name is 'X::Y::' (ends in two colons).  And in fact, I get this error:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

{
    package X::Y;

    our $user = 10;
    say $user;

    say __PACKAGE__;
    say $X::Y::{user}; 
    say __PACKAGE__->{user};
}

--output:--
10
X::Y
*X::Y::user
Use of uninitialized value in say at 2.pl line 13.
```

If the code actually creates a hash named %X::Y somewhere, then the code will run without errors:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;


%X::Y = (); #This hash has nothing to do with the hash named 
            #%X::Y::, which is the symbol table for the 
            #X::Y package.  

$X::Y{user} = 'hello';


{
    package X::Y;

    sub get_user {
        say __PACKAGE__->{user};
    }

    get_user;
}


--output:--
hello
```

As mentioned in the comment, the %X::Y hash has nothing to do with the X::Y package.  In fact, the line:

```
%X::Y = ();
```

explicitly declares a variable called Y in the X package.  The X package and the X::Y package are two different packages.

> And there's no package variables defined

The sub name is a package variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

{
    package X::Y;

    sub get_user {say 'hello';}

    say $X::Y::{get_user};

}

--output:--
*X::Y::get_user
```

The fact that a typeglob for the name 'get_user' exists, means that the code uses at least one global variable named 'get_user'.